# Using the rational root test (subject Math GRE exam 9768 Q.31)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, gre-exam

> [image]

I used the rational root test and my answer was B as -5 does not divide 9, but the correct answer is C. Could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: `-5 does not divide 9` That's not what the rational root test says. $\,-5 = \cfrac{-5}{1}\,$ where $1 \mid 9\,$, and $5$ *could* divide $b$.

Comment: To see that (B) is wrong, let $a=0$ and $b=9\cdot 5^5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Rational Root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), if $\frac{p}{q}$ is a root(in lowest terms) then $p \mid b$ and $q \mid 9$ provided $b \neq 0$.

As $4 \nmid 9$, therefore $\frac 14$ cannot be a root.

Comment: and the GRE has successfully tested if you know the rational root test.

Comment: Wrong. Correct is: $ $  if $\,p/q\,$ is a root in *lowest terms* (i.e. $p,q$ coprime) then....

Answer (score 2):

The rational roots must be of the form

$$\dfrac{\text{divisor of b}}{\text{divisor of 9}}$$

The only number not of this form is $\frac 14$.